# Analyze height data using a digital elevation map

Tags: python, gdal

i ran the following code on python 2.7:

```
import sys, struct
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import gdalconst

minLat = -48
maxLat = -33
minLong = 165
maxLong = 179

dataset = gdal.Open("C:\Python27\l10g.gz")
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

t = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
success,tInverse = gdal.InvGeoTransform(t)
if not success:
    print("Failed!")
    sys.exit(1)

x1, y1= gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(tInverse, minLong, minLat)
x2, y2= gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(tInverse, maxLong, maxLat)

minX = int(min(x1, x2))
maxX = int(max(x1, x2))
minY = int(min(y1, y2))
maxY = int(max(y1, y2))

width = (maxX - minX) + 1
fmt = "<" + ("h"* width)

for y in range(minY, maxY+1):
    scanline = band.ReadRaster(minX, y, width, 1, width, 1,
                               gdalconst.GDT_Int16)
    values = struct.unpack(fmt, scanline)

    for values in values:
        try:
            histogram[value] += 1
        except KeyError:
            histogram[value] = 1
for height in sorted(histogram.keys()):
    print (height, hsitogram[height])
```

for which i am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/demagain.py", line 34, in <module>
    values = struct.unpack(fmt, scanline)
error: unpack requires a string argument of length 3362
```

Why is this python unpack function giving an error?

Comment: Since `struct` and `unpack` are part of Python rather than GDAL, I think you will be better researching this one via [so].

Comment: You also have a typo. Change `hsitogram` to `histogram` in the last line

Comment: Cross-posted to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264090/getting-histigram-of-dem-data

Answer (score 2):

Use band.XSize instead of width e.g.

```
fmt = "<" + ("h" * band.XSize)
```

In the ReadRaster use row and column numbers, not the real coordinates e.g.

```
for y in range(band.YSize):
    scanline = band.ReadRaster(0, y, band.XSize, 1, band.XSize, 1, band.DataType)
```

Check the data type with gdalinfo if it is really 2byte integer.

Comment: o it is working, can you please elaborate why width is not equal to band.Xsize

Comment: after using this code i am getting same error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\demofnewzeland.py", line 32, in <module>
    values = struct.unpack(fmt, scanline)
error: unpack requires a string argument of length 21600

Comment: In your code width is a coordinate difference, it won't be correct if the grid size is not 1.

Comment: Have your tried `gdalinfo C:\Python27\l10g.gz`? Try to use a Python debugger or add some print statement to find whether the error is at beginning or at the end of the file.

Comment: on typing this it is giving an error- gdalinfo C:\Python27\l10g.gz
                                                       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Try it with any simple image (jpg/png/tif) file e.g. `gdalinfo your_image.jpg`. What is inside your gzipped file. Is it a valid image file? Have you tried to uncompress? Why do you use gz file?

Comment: i have down loaded this file from-  http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/topo/elev/esri/hdr   which is newzeland's map .  with .png or with .gz imge above code is executing completely on gui of python but when i am saving and executing then it is giving a error